# WPF c# .net framework 4.8 x:Bind

Tags: c#, wpf, xbind

I read about `x:Bind`, it has better performance vs `Binding`. But in my application WPF C# with .NET Framework 4.8 when I put `x:Bind` in any part (`TextBox Text="{x:Bind ...}"`), Visual Studio say to me *"Bind is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project."*

Is not possible you x:Bind in WPF C# Application for Desktop? Or what I need to do for use it?

Comment: `x:Bind` is for `UWP` apps and not `WPF`- there even is an issue on GitHub to request x:bind for wpf https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/130

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid `x:Bind` is currently only supported in the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and not in WPF/.NET Framework so the error message is correct.

You can host UWP controls in a WPF app using [XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands) but there is no way to use a compiled binding directly on a WPF dependency property.

Answer (score 6):

`x:Bind` is now available in non-UWP, Windows 10 desktop apps with WinUI 3.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/get-started-winui3-for-desktop

`x:Bind` for WPF in .NET Framework and .NET Core is still not supported.

Answer (score 3):

Try my implementation of the x:Bind Markup Extension for WPF (and Xamarin Forms)
https://github.com/levitali/CompiledBindings

The nuget is CompiledBindings.WPF