# C# reset wpf toolkit CheckComboBox

Tags: c#, checkbox, combobox, wpftoolkit

I have a CheckComboBox from the wpfToolkit and i want to reset it. That means that all items in the  CheckComboBox are unchecked. Already tried to set the SelectedValue to an empty string. This works for the function itself, but in the UI the items are still checked.

I also work with Bindings and the MVVM pattern:

```
 <wpfTool:CheckComboBox IsSelectAllActive="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Filter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedFilterItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="140"/>
```

Comment: Try setting the binding mode of `SelectedValue` to `TwoWay`.

Comment: there's `SelectAll` and `UnSelectAll` method.

Comment: I tried Mode=TwoWay, but i doesn't change anything. 

These methods could not be found. Do i need something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. Its important to set SelectedValue and SelectedItem to null. Also set Mode=TwoWay and UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for the SelectedValue property:

```
SelectedValue="{x:Bind SelectedFilterItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Then you should be able to reset it to null by changing your SelectedFilterItem property.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i think x:Bind is not available in WPF according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153403/wpf-c-sharp-net-framework-4-8-xbind